# Grafana Transform Convert Field Type Missing

Tags: grafana

I am using the CSV plugin for grafana

I have multiple columns in the CSV but I am stripping out excess data.
Column Name: Example Value
day: 2023-01-30
steps: 1234
Active Calories: 5678

When I try to make a new dashboard and select Day, steps, and active calories(ac going forward); I set day to Time and ac and steps to number. I get no graph but with steps and ac in the legend. If I leave the date as a string I get a message that there is no time variable.

I have read elsewhere that I need to use the transform tab and set up a transformation to convert the date (string) to the proper type for Grafana to use it. I have found in the documentation "convert field type" as a transformation type that I believe I am supposed to use.

However, the transformation "convert field type" isn't available. It's not in the list and I can't find it by searching.

any assistance/guidance is appreciated.

I am running Grafana 8.0.4 in docker.

I have searched but can't figure out why convert field type isn't an option in my transformations.

I would expect that to be an option.

Comment: Could it be that this was not availabe in v8.0.x yet? See https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v8.0/panels/transformations/types-options/ - not mentioned in the docs of the old version but in latest and 8.3 (https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v8.3/panels/transformations/types-options/#convert-field-type).

Comment: That was it. Thanks 8.3.0 works